# Select default tab on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-tabs

I would like the first tab to be 'selected' upon page load.

Hi, I would like the first tab, 'Discover', to be selected upon page load. I have run multiple versions of the same code functionality in Javascript and nothing seems to be working. I am wondering whether my code format in Javascript or HTML is correct.

I have used this as a reference: https://codepen.io/PeteTalksWeb/pen/vmyJBd

Any feedback or help on this subject would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabbable-line">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs text-center">
  <li class="active">
   <a href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab">Discover</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#tabs-2" data-toggle="tab">Planning</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#tabs-3" data-toggle="tab">Marketing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#tabs-4" data-toggle="tab">Growth</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs-1">
<div class="col-md-6 margin-btm-30">
 <img src="img/process-1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-shadow" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <h4>Integration of business</h4>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-2">
<div class="col-md-6 margin-btm-30">
 <img src="img/process-2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-shadow" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <h4>Integration of business</h4>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-3">
<div class="col-md-6 margin-btm-30">
 <img src="img/process-3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-shadow" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <h4>Integration of business</h4>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-4">
<div class="col-md-6 margin-btm-30">
 <img src="img/process-4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-shadow" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <h4>Integration of business</h4>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="tabid"></div>
```

```
<script>
 $("#tabs").tabs({
 active: 0,
 activate: function (event, ui) {
 var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
 }
 });
</script>
```

I expected the tab/link to be selected upon page load, but the output instead was that the tab 'flashed' as if selected and faded shortly after.

EDIT
I received this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function
What does this mean?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Are you including jQuery and jQuery UI? Are you running your JS at the end of the page or in a document.ready handler?

Comment: Hi @j08691, thanks for checking - I did not include the jQuery and jQuery UI at first, although I have added it now but does not seem to work. I am running my JS at the end of my HTML page. Is that the correct way of running it?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below shows that it is working fine. Please check the following:

1. Your javascript is wrapped with a document.ready function: Either

`$(function(){`

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

(both work the same - see the below StackSnippet for how the first was used)

2. You have included all necessary libraries (the CSS, the jQuery.js and the jQueryUI.js files) -- as in the below snippet. You can include these just as they are within the `<head>` tags of your page.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    active: 0,
    activate: function (event, ui) {
      var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
    }
  });
}); //end document.ready
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" >
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs" class="tabbable-line">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs text-center">
  <li class="active">
   <a href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab">Discover</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#tabs-2" data-toggle="tab">Planning</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#tabs-3" data-toggle="tab">Marketing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#tabs-4" data-toggle="tab">Growth</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs-1">
<div class="col-md-6 margin-btm-30">
 <img src="img/process-1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-shadow" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <h4>Integration of business</h4>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-2">
<div class="col-md-6 margin-btm-30">
 <img src="img/process-2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-shadow" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <h4>Integration of business</h4>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-3">
<div class="col-md-6 margin-btm-30">
 <img src="img/process-3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-shadow" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <h4>Integration of business</h4>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-4">
<div class="col-md-6 margin-btm-30">
 <img src="img/process-4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-shadow" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <h4>Integration of business</h4>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="tabid"></div>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @cssyphus, thank you for your suggestion. I have added edited the code as you suggested and somehow the code is still not running. I will check the console for errors. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your code and created a JSFiddle with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b6ac7fqe/).

Your code works fine and as you will see I have been sure to include both the the following resources;

Jquery itself - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

Jquery UI - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js

In my example change the following;

```
active: 1,
```

to

```
active: 0,
```

and you will see that a different tab is selected.

Comment: Hi @Will, thank you for your suggestion. Glad to see that the code is working, although it is still not working my side... I have included the jQuery and jQueryUI as shown in your example, but my JS is running from my HTML page - is that not perhaps part of what is causing the error?

Comment: Can you show me how you have included the resources?

Comment: Hi @Will, sure. Please see below:

``
<!-- Script-->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- custom css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
``

Comment: <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  No closing script tag in your code??

Comment: Hi @Will, apologies - I did a reference check and I must have accidentally removed it in my comment. It does have a closing script tag in my code.